# IIS: Redirect all pages where the page doesn't exist to the old server

Tags: iis

I have a IIS server running on windows 2003 named Foo.
Now I want to create a new IIS server running on windows 2008.
My Idea is to slowly move the applications over to the new server while having both servers in production. In order to do this I need to redirect all traffic from the new server where the pages don't exist to the old server. Is this possible?
Lets say that I haven't moved over FooOld/Bar/page.asp?id=10,
When the user tries to access it at Foo/Bar/page.asp?id=10 I want the server to redirect this to FooOld/Bar/page.asp?id=10. If possible the user shouldn't even see that it has been redirected it should still see Foo/Bar/page.asp?id=10.

*Edited*

I found that [Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/expand/ApplicationRequestRouting) can be used as a [reverse proxy](http://blogs.iis.net/wonyoo/archive/2008/07/09/application-request-routing-arr-as-a-reverse-proxy.aspx). If I have understood how a reverse proxy works then that should work as I want to, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You could probably do this with a custom 404 page.  I've done it before in a more general manner, but I'm thinking that if you used an ASP (or aspx), read the query string, constructed the new URL based on that, then redirected to the new URL it should work fine.

It'll break on form submissions of course, but I don't think there's an easy way there.

Comment: +1 This answer would be the way I would approach the task...